# Ideal EC2 Instance type for magento 2.2.3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, magento2

I am running the magento 2.2.3 version on AWS EC2 currently on c5x.large the performance seems fine for me with proper page speed backed by cloudfront and Redis.

Due to cost optimization I have decided to use m4.large instance and saw the degradation in performance magento page speed from 2.5 second to 6.6 second. I noticed the cpu usage with m4 large type instance it was going up during cache creation and was neutral at other time. I also noticed the cache flush operation from magento admin panel which took approx 3.5 min where as in case of C5 xlarge it was taking 50 seconds to complete same operation.

Is something wrong with my application or it's the cache operation that has direct connection with my cpu? What will be the right Instance series to be choosen for magento 2.2.3 on production?

Also this was not the case with magento 2.1.6, the cache flush operations are very normal even with t2.medium instances we used t2.medium for dev instances earlier.

Specifications:
M4 large :  2 vcpu 8 GB RAM
C5 Xlarge : 4 vcpu 8 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

You really need to understand what the limiting factors are in your application, and pick an appropriate instance family.

In addition to having two additional virtual cores, the C5 runs on a newer CPU family (so will usually have a slightly higher clock speed), and supports higher networking throughput than the M4.large.

Another big difference between the two is the maximum supported I/O rate.  The C5.xlarge supports 16,000 IOPS while the M4 is limited to 3,600.  This is related to the reduced networking capacity.

So determine if CPU, Networking or I/O is causing the slowdown, and then determine if the cost/benefits of moving to a more appropriate instance type are worth it.